# Reading a JSON file using pandas in a desired format

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a JSON file that contains:

```
{
    "getYearsListOverview": {
        "sp_name": "analytics.year_overview_drop_down",
        "sp_input_params": {
            "req_url_query_params": [],
            "req_body_params": []
        },
        "sp_output_datasets": [],
        "page_name": "home"
    },
    "getRankingsDataPerformanceReport": {
        "sp_name": "analytics.get_performance_ranking_data",
        "sp_input_params": {
            "req_url_query_params": [
                ["@scroll_index", "index"]
            ],
            "req_body_params": [
                ["@event_type_id", "event_type_id"],
                ["@season", "season"],
                ["@athlete_guid", "athlete_guid"]
            ]
        },
        "sp_output_datasets": [],
        "number_of_output_datasets_for_customized_template": 4,
        "customised_response_template": {
            "performance_value_list": [],
            "rankings_table": [],
            "level_values": []
        },
        "page_name": "performancereport"
    }
}
```

I want this to get converted into a `pandas` dataframe. The dataframe should have the following columns like:

```
sp_name      
req_url_query_params  
req_body_params    
sp_output_datasets    
number_of_output_datasets_for_customized_template    
performance_value_list   
rankings_table    
level_values   
page_name
```

I am using the following code snippets:

```
with open(os.path.join(filepath,json_file),'r',encoding="utf-8") as json_file:
  j_f = json.load(json_file)
df_1 = json_normalize(j_f)
```

But this is giving me a dataframe whose columns are like below:

```
getYearsListOverview.sp_name    
getYearsListOverview.sp_input_params.req_url_query_params    
getYearsListOverview.sp_input_params.req_body_params
```

And the values are being populated as per JSON.

How to get the desired column names here. A small change in JSON data structure is acceptable.

Comment: Any help on this?

Answer (score 0):

To simply rename the columns

```
for col in df_1.columns:
    new_col_name = col.split('.')[-1]
    df_1.rename(columns = {col: new_col_name},inplace=True)
print(df_1.columns)
```

Output:

```
Index(['sp_name', 'req_url_query_params', 'req_body_params',
   'sp_output_datasets', 'page_name', 'sp_name', 'req_url_query_params',
   'req_body_params', 'sp_output_datasets',
   'number_of_output_datasets_for_customized_template',
   'performance_value_list', 'rankings_table', 'level_values',
   'page_name'],
  dtype='object')
```

So your JSON file has two upper level elements which contains the same variables which creates conflicts in column naming when you create ONE dataframe from that JSON file. What you can do is divide the JSON object into two.

```
dict0 = dict(list(j_f.items())[:1])
dict1 = dict(list(j_f.items())[1:])
```

And then turn back into dataframes again

```
df_0 = pd.json_normalize(dict0)
df_1 = pd.json_normalize(dict1)
```

And work them indivdually. Resulting in two dataframes with no column collision.